# Button Inside Legend Inside Fieldset Not Clickable

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

A button inside the legend of a fieldset is not clickable when the fieldset is a flexbox, this only happens in mobile Safari:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
fieldset {
  display: flex;
}
legend {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
button:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <fieldset class="col" data-un="u_SkwBump">
      <legend>
        <button>Click</button>
      </legend>
    </fieldset>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://uevs8r.csb.app/) is also a CodeSandbox, since the snippet is hard to get  running on mobile.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

I found [this](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9) flexbug, but I don't think that's the issue here, the flexbox works well on the fieldset as you can see, the columns are displayed side by side (at least on my phone).  Just the button not being clickable.

Comment: FWIW I am running into the same issue so it has been a thing for months at least.